# Repeator Control load using ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am using a asp.net , since data is large i am showing a progress bar initially using jquery  and then making a call to page through ajax and wanted to load repeater control. Not able to achieve it , Need a help please 
ASPX PART:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>  
    <table> 
          <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">      
          <HeaderTemplate>        
            <thead> 
            <tr>
                 <td>Category Name</td>

            </tr>
           </thead>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>

      <tr>
       <td><%# Eval("CategoryName")%></td>
          </tr>

     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
 </table>
 </div>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

VB CODE BEHIND PART:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles    Me.Load
    Dim requestType As String = Request.QueryString("type")

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(requestType) Then
        Select Case requestType.ToUpper
            Case "REPEATORLOAD"
                Repeater1.DataSource = GenerateBinDetails()
                Repeater1.DataBind()
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

AJAX SCRIPT PART:

```
 var urlPath = "../views/Reports/RegionalStockHoldings.aspx?type=repeatorLoad"
    $.ajax({
        url: urlPath,
        type: "POST",
        cache: false
    }).done(function (html) {
        debugger;
        //how can i bind it to my repeator control , I am getting the whole html data of      the page.
    });
```

Comment: 1. Use webmethod 2. You need to send the html format of your Repeater1 control. 3.Important thing is how to get the instance of `Repeater1` in ajax call with out sending the viewstate information for your request

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you will be able to bind the repeater control from the jQuery code you provided.

However, what you could do is move your bind code to a WebMethod on the RegionalStockHoldings.aspx page  Something along the lines of this

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod> _
Public Sub BindRepeater() 
    Repeater1.DataSource = GenerateBinDetails()
    Repeater1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

You can then call this code from your jQuery call like so

```
var urlPath = "../views/Reports/RegionalStockHoldings.aspx/BindRepeater"
$.ajax({
    url: urlPath,
    type: "POST",
    cache: false
}).done(function (html) {
    debugger;
    alert("bound repeater");
});
```